# How to repeat nth-child rules for an infinite sequence in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I try to repeat some CSS rules using `nth-child` as follows

```css
.pattern-row:nth-child(3) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(5) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(7) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(10) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(12) .pattern-keyboard-key
/*
,.pattern-row:nth-child(15) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(17) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(19) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(22) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(24) .pattern-keyboard-key,

...
*/
{
border-top: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

I found `nth-child(an+b)` to cycle rules but it does not fit my need because the sequence is not linear.

Comment: If the numbers can't be arrived at using an equation then I don't think there is a way with CSS. You may have to assign classes or use some scripting.

Comment: *....sequence is not linear...* then css can not work out for u mate, either change your DOM layout or break your entire layout in groups so that they fit in an equation...then use `nth-child` or `jQuery` :)

Comment: From what has been shown in the question the sequence does actually repeat, the steps are just not evenly spaced. The sequence is +3, +2, +2, +3, +2, repeat. It may not be possible to target every step in the sequence with a single :nth-child selector, but it can be done with 5 selectors, one for each of the 5 steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target each number in your 5 step sequence with separate `:nth-child` selectors.

e.g. `12n - 9` will match 3, 15, 27, 39, etc.

```
.pattern-row:nth-child(12n - 9) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(12n - 7) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(12n - 5) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(12n - 2) .pattern-keyboard-key,
.pattern-row:nth-child(12n) .pattern-keyboard-key {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mvve6kub/